# SEO link transfer from example.com to example.group.com.au

Tags: redirects, subdomain, seo

I have a group of 3 businesses currently managed through 3 separate domains call it `example1.com.au`, `example2.com.au` and `example3.com.au`.

The business wants to move to the following structure: `example1.group.com.au`, `example2.group.com.au`,  `example3.group.com.au` and `group.com.au/blog`.

This is mainly to aggregate the SEO efforts and blogs. I am wondering is if there is a way to avoid losing page authority and link attribution when using the new URLs. I looked at DNS redirect but the links are lost.

Any advice on how to perform the redirects without losing ranking would be appreciated.

Comment: So you put in three (or four?) redirects. I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask?

Comment: I am looking for a way to move the sites without losing page authority or links. I am pretty new to this sort of thing....

Answer (score 1):

To begin. There is *NO* such thing as a DNS redirect. DNS *ONLY* assigns a domain name to an IP address. Nothing more. So please throw this out of your mind.

There is only one option.

You can combine all of the content from all four sites, however, in order not to lose the advantages you have gained over the past years, you must keep all four sites and at the very least, a blanket 301 redirect from each site to the new site. This assumes that the fours sites do not have structure overlaps. If there are overlaps then you will have to make some more custom redirects. You can still wildcard much of this. But you will need to make a road-map before taking on the work so that you have a plan.

Having said that, I always advise making the new domain stand on it's own. This means that a vigorous back link campaign must be taken in order to replicate the original back link profile at a minimum. The reason why this is important is because the day will come that you will want to delete the old domains. Replicating the back link profile as much as you can and even increasing the back link profile on the new domain will make this possible.